# IOS - NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint UIKeyboardAssistantBar

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, constraints

Helllo,

I am working on a little check-in check-out app for IOS.

Everything was working all good, and I was about to implement a new feature, but all of the sudden I get this weird constraint error while I didn't do anything with constraints.

> 2018-03-22 08:29:53.252797+0100 Checkin[20633:642598]
>   [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
>     Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one
>   you don't want.   Try this:       (1) look at each constraint and try to
>   figure out which you don't expect;        (2) find the code that added the
>   unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.    (Note: If you're
>   seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand,
>   refer to the documentation for the UIView property
>   translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)  (
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "
>   (active)>",
>       "
>   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f806473b330 )>",
>       "
>   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f806473b330 )>" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
>   
>   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f806473b330 )>
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
>   to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
>   UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
>    may also be helpful. 2018-03-22 08:29:53.254300+0100
>   Checkin[20633:642598] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously
>   satisfy constraints.  Probably at least one of the constraints in the
>   following list is one you don't want.     Try this:       (1) look at each
>   constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect;          (2) find
>   the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.
>     (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you
>   don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property
>   translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)  (
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "
>   (active)>",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "
>   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f806473a610 )>",
>       "
>   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f806473a610 )>" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
>   to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
>   UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
>    may also be helpful. 2018-03-22 08:29:53.255549+0100
>   Checkin[20633:642598] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously
>   satisfy constraints.  Probably at least one of the constraints in the
>   following list is one you don't want.     Try this:       (1) look at each
>   constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect;          (2) find
>   the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.
>     (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you
>   don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property
>   translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)  (
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "
>   (active)>",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "= UIView:0x7f80647705d0.bottom   (active)>",
>       "
>   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f806473a610 )>",
>       "
>   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f806473a610 )>" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
>   = UIView:0x7f80647705d0.bottom   (active)>
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
>   to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
>   UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
>    may also be helpful. 2018-03-22 08:29:53.256507+0100
>   Checkin[20633:642598] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously
>   satisfy constraints.  Probably at least one of the constraints in the
>   following list is one you don't want.     Try this:       (1) look at each
>   constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect;          (2) find
>   the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.
>     (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you
>   don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property
>   translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)  (
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "
>   (active)>",
>       "
>   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f8064737760 )>",
>       "
>   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f8064737760 )>" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
>   
>   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f8064737760 )>
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
>   to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
>   UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
>    may also be helpful. 2018-03-22 08:29:53.259284+0100
>   Checkin[20633:642598] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously
>   satisfy constraints.  Probably at least one of the constraints in the
>   following list is one you don't want.     Try this:       (1) look at each
>   constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect;          (2) find
>   the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.
>     (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you
>   don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property
>   translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)  (
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "
>   (active)>",
>       "
>   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f806473a610 )>",
>       "
>   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f806473a610 )>" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
>   
>   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f806473a610 )>
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
>   to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
>   UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
>    may also be helpful.

I have a couple fields like this:
https://gyazo.com/e04d38e812374cacbde3c4d28bea4d79

When I click on a field this thing pops up: https://gyazo.com/e8c259e6ad280646a9f72d9a32b6638d

No errors so far, but as soon I click on any other field I get that error.

https://gyazo.com/50aebfee537070052e632c9762e27574

When the error has appeared once it doesn't appear anymore until I go to an other page and back.

How do I solve this?

Comment: It seems all the fields are in stack view. And when you tap on any field do you handle anything like moving screen up/down to be visible above keyboard?

Comment: This is how my scene is:
https://gyazo.com/db3dc460298e66e5c000587516154376
I am not aware if I handle anything like moving screen up/down. Maybe something is handling that, but I don't know about it.

Comment: Ok next question do you manage any constraints on keyboard hide show notification?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. Where can I see that?

Comment: Have you used nay keyboard avoiding library

Comment: try to add the break point and check when it breaks

Comment: No, I have not used that library, and I have tried to set breakpoints but that ends up in the assembly code.